# Can it be possible to convert base64 string to Rich text area image using Rest Webservice in salesforce?

Tags: apex, integration, webservices

My requirement was to capture the base64 string, which is passed as a webservice parameter - that needs to be converted as an image in Rich Text area field in custom object in salesforce.

I need to achieve it without storing it in attachments, as i have some other invoices as attachments.

Is there any other possibilities to achieve it?

Looking forward for your replies...

Comment: Is there any alternate solution to achieve this ??

Comment: Probably your question isn't clear or specific for anyone to answer Bhuvan. It doesn't look like you've even attempted anything yet, either that or diving into the apex documentation in regards to encoding, rich text content or anything like that may be a good start. Is there a reason why you think it's not possible ?

Comment: Mind posting that as an aswer and accepting it so that others know the question is resolved or can learn from your experience ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for you help. I have achieved it using document object to store the base64 image and updated the same to rich text area field. @SamuelDeRycke : I have some invoices in attachment objects so while updating the image the previous one is of no use, which needs to be deleted(bit complex to identify and delete) instead using document object to store bast64 string and update through apex into rich text area field in the custom object. Thanks – Bhuvan Kumar